# R - log return of consecutive dataframe elements

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that looks like:

```
> head(statadata_one_every_5_minutes)
         date  time_greece gmt_offset_greece price_greece           time_and_date gmt_offset_greece_test time_and_date_correct time_and_date_difference
1  2009-12-01 08:30:04.548                +2      2275.32 2009-12-01 08:30:04.548                      2   2009-12-01 06:30:04                   0 secs
6  2009-12-01 08:35:04.380                +2      2297.74 2009-12-01 08:35:04.380                      2   2009-12-01 06:35:04                   0 secs
11 2009-12-01 08:40:04.328                +2      2322.04 2009-12-01 08:40:04.328                      2   2009-12-01 06:40:04                   0 secs
16 2009-12-01 08:45:04.365                +2      2325.51 2009-12-01 08:45:04.365                      2   2009-12-01 06:45:04                   0 secs
21 2009-12-01 08:50:04.463                +2      2331.36 2009-12-01 08:50:04.463                      2   2009-12-01 06:50:04                   0 secs
26 2009-12-01 08:55:04.403                +2      2335.09 2009-12-01 08:55:04.403                      2   2009-12-01 06:55:04                   0 secs
   ID price_greece_numeric
1   1              2275.32
6   6              2297.74
11 11              2322.04
16 16              2325.51
21 21              2331.36
26 26              2335.09
```

I am trying to calculate the log returns of consecutive elements using the following command:

```
> n <- length(statadata_one_every_5_minutes$price_greece_numeric)
> statadata_one_every_5_minutes$log_returns <- log(statadata_one_every_5_minutes$price_greece_numeric[-1]/statadata_one_every_5_minutes$price_greece_numeric[-n])
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, log_returns, value = c(0.00980532931107567,  : 
  replacement has 61897 rows, data has 61898
```

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Yes I want to calculate the log returns of the prices. I added a few more data points in my original post.

Comment: What I want is to calculate the log return between the elements of the 2nd row vs the 1st row, then the log returns of the 3rd row vs the 2nd row, all the way to the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)

statadata_one_every_5_minutes %>% 
  mutate(log_returns = log(price_greece_numeric/lag(price_greece_numeric)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data$value[-1]` removes row #1, which gives you a dataframe that is shorter by 1 - this is also what the error states, as you are trying to rbind this (short) result to the original dataframe.

You did not specify what to do with the last row, and as you did not a pastable data.frame, I can just give a a sample way to do this:

```
log(c(0,data$value)/c(data$value,0))[-1]
```

The `[-1]` at the end removes the first value, so that the first row of the result is then `log(data$value[1]/data$value[2])`.

Comment: ok so what should I write in order to calculate the log returns of the dataframe?

Comment: The first row of the result should be NA (empty) then the second should have the value `log(data$value[3]/data$value[2])` . Can you edit your response to get that?

Comment: What about the last row? Are you sure you don't want first row -> NA, second row log(row2/row1)

Comment: yes I want what you are saying... what is the code to do that?